# Как написать маску для датафрейма для временного интервала в pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Есть датафрейм, в котором одна из колонок `date` хранит в даты (тип `datetime64`). Мне нужно написать маску датафрейма, чтобы у меня остались только строки, в которых даты входят в этот временной интервал.
Если более конкретно, то интервал - 6 дней от вводимой пользователем даты.

Когда пишу так, т. е. только с верхней границей интервала, то он не возмущается.

```
mask_date = sales['date'] < pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01') - pd.offsets.Day(3)
sales[mask_date].sort_values('date')
```

Когда добавляю нижнюю границу, то выдаёт ошибку.

```
mask_date = sales['date'] < pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01') - pd.offsets.Day(3) and sales['date'] > pd.to_datetime('2010-01-06')
sales[mask_date].sort_values('date')
```

Пытался и через`and`, и через `&`, и с обех сторон границы просто поставить.

Ошибка:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-f64dcd515cb6> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 mask_date = sales['date'] < pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01') - pd.offsets.Day(3) and sales['date'] > pd.to_datetime('2010-01-06')
      2 mask_date
      3 sales[mask_date].sort_values('date')

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1525     @final
   1526     def __nonzero__(self) -> NoReturn:
-> 1527         raise ValueError(
   1528             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1529             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2):

Почему бы просто не использовать метод `.between()`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': pd.date_range('2023-01-01', '2023-05-01')})
date, delta = '2023-03-15', pd.DateOffset(6)  # введенная пользователм дата, кол-во дней до и после
date = pd.to_datetime(date)
df = df[df.Date.between(date - delta, date + delta)]
print(df)
```

```
         Date
67 2023-03-09
68 2023-03-10
69 2023-03-11
70 2023-03-12
71 2023-03-13
72 2023-03-14
73 2023-03-15
74 2023-03-16
75 2023-03-17
76 2023-03-18
77 2023-03-19
78 2023-03-20
79 2023-03-21
```

PS. Границы в [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) можно настраивать (левая / правая / обе : включать / не включать)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй использовать & и, закинуть условие в скобки.

```
mask_date = (sales['date'] < pd.to_datetime('2020-01-01') - pd.offsets.Day(3)) & (sales['date'] > pd.to_datetime('2010-01-06'))
sales[mask_date].sort_values('date')
```